# Cancel All Market Updates/Downloads at Once

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I just re-flashed CM 6.1 and when I opened up the market to download Titanium Backup, 27 apps started to automatically download, simultaneously. I'm not sure why they'd do that, and they never have done this before after flashing a fresh ROM.  Needless to say, is there any way to stop all downloads all at once, or prevent this from happening in the future?

Android 2.2.1, Moto Droid 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is the result of a new synchronization option in 2.1 or 2.2. On the first boot it asks whether you want to store some information about your apps online. I found it quite confusingly worded and was surprised by this effect. IIRC you can prevent this from happening by refusing all the synchronization on the first boot. And I learned to only update when on wifi..

Comment: That's it. I was so quick to click I didn't notice that change. That would actually be very useful if I wasn't using Titanium Backup.

Comment: Interesting ... the Google backup has never worked for me!  Opposite problem :P

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing you data and cache on the Download Manager... Menu button > Settings Applications > Manage Applications (wait 15-30 sec to load)> Download Manager clear cache and clear data.

Comment: wow  thanks i tried your way and it worked for me. it was easy now my phone is normal agn and it runs much faster than before thx

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're flashing an ancient ROM, where the built-in apps all are now outdated?

For a fast way to stop downloads, shut off the Wifi, 3G, and all connectivity?

Comment: No, the ROM was released 12 days ago. All the apps that started downloading were apps that were previously installed and had nothing to do with my new ROM.  I wonder if that's a new function of the market?  It basically backs up your app list and reinstalls them after a fresh install?  Anyway, thanks for the "unplug" solution.  I'm still hoping theres a cleaner method.